# No Background Title in mdframed

Tags: mdframed, backgrounds, frame-title

I'm dealing with `mdframed`. I wrote some text in a grey background frame.
Then I want to display the frame title, but I don't want that the box which contains the frame title is visible (actually it's white). I just want a box with the title and no background.

Here the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed, xcolor}

    \newenvironment{myenv}[1]
      {\mdfsetup{
        frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space#1\space}},
        linecolor=black,
        innertopmargin=10pt,
        backgroundcolor=gray!10!white,
        frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
        frametitlealignment=\center
        }
      \begin{mdframed}%
      }
      {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{myenv}{Sintesi}
    {\small Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga}
    \end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

And the output it's the following:

[image: Frametitle White Background]

Where the frame title, "Sintesi", has a white background.

How can I make the title without background?

Thank you very much!

R.

Comment: I am not sure about the desired ouput. Would     `frametitle={\space#1\space},` this be what you need?

Comment: Thanks for answering me!
I desire a transparent title box. In this way, the writing "Sintesi" has the same background of the box (grey) and the same background of the page (white).

I don't know if now it's more clear, probably not..if not I can try to explain again

Comment: I used `frametitle={\space#1\space}` but it just put the writing "Sintesi" above the grey box and I want in the same position it is now!

Comment: Please see my answer below. Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: Absolutely YES. I'm trying to understand what did you write, it's not easy for me, sorry

Comment: Don't worry. I added some explanation to my answer about the placement calculations.

Comment: Thank you!
But, what about if I want the black line around the box?
I commented the line `hidealllines=true` and the black line appeared around the grey box. But now it's cutting the frame title!

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Like that?

Comment: Like that it's perfect. Exactly what I wanted.
I imagine you @Gonzalo receive billions of thanks each day, mine it will be a drop in the Ocean. So I give you a thanks in Italian style, as I'm Italian, probably it will be more powerful: grazie mille!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First version

One option is to place the title using `singleextra` (for unbroken frames) and `firstextra` (for broken frames) using a TikZ `\node` at the desired location and with transparent background. The calc library can be used to place the node at the middle of the upper part of the box, using the special coordinates `(O)` and `(P)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\mdfsetup{
    firstextra={
    \node[opacity=0,text opacity=1]
      at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {#1};
    },
    singleextra={
    \node[opacity=0,text opacity=1] 
      at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {#1};
    },
    linecolor=black,
    font=\small,
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!10!white,
    }
  \begin{mdframed}%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{Sintesi}
Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A zoomed-in image showing the title with the two inherited background colors:

[image]

You can further adjust the positioning using appropriate shifts:

```
firstextra={
\node[opacity=0,text opacity=1]
  at ([yshift=1pt] $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {#1};
},
singleextra={
\node[opacity=0,text opacity=1] 
  at ([yshift=1pt] $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {#1};
},
```

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\mdfsetup{
    firstextra={
    \node[text opacity=1,fill=white] 
      (title)
      at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {\phantom{#1}};
    \fill[gray!10!white] (title.west|-P) rectangle (title.south east);  
    \node[text opacity=1] 
      at (title) {#1};
    },
    singleextra={
    \node[text opacity=1,fill=white] 
      (title)
      at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {\phantom{#1}};
    \fill[gray!10!white] (title.west|-P) rectangle (title.south east);  
    \node[text opacity=1] 
      at (title) {#1};
    },
    linecolor=black,
    font=\small,
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!10!white,
    }
  \begin{mdframed}%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{Sintesi}
Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the zoomed-in inake for the title:

[image]

The coordinate `(O)` is the lower left corner of the frame, `(P)` is the upper right corner, so `(O|-P)` is the upper left corner, and `( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ )` gives the middle point in the upper segment of the frame.

Comment: I was just asking how can I adjust the positing :)

But, following your opinion, is it better like this (with no background) or before, with the white background?

Thank you for helping me @Gonzalo

Comment: @user51937 I'd rather use a white background and a frame around the title; something like    `\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
      {\mdfsetup{
        frametitle={\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\space#1\space}},
        linecolor=black,
        innertopmargin=10pt,
        backgroundcolor=gray!10!white,
        frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
        frametitlealignment=\center
        }
      \begin{mdframed}
      }
      {\end{mdframed}}`

Comment: @user51937 Sorry for the poor formatting of the code in my previous comment, but writing code in comments is painful!

Comment: Do not even ask sorry, you rule!
I'm trying to compare the two ways, I have all the night to understand your code above and finally to chose which way to chose. Grazie ancora!